# Spark catalyst optimizer cast exception

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 (`Foo` and `Bar`) classes, each implements one interface.

Application has method which check some condition for interface-objects.

```
private boolean check(Interface1 obj)
```

I apply this method to both classes:

```
Dataset<Foo> foos = getStapSession()....load().as(Encoders.bean(Foo.class));
Dataset<Bar> bars = getStapSession()....load().as(Encoders.bean(Bar.class));

foos.filter((FilterFunction<Foo>) this::check).collectAsList();
bars.filter((FilterFunction<Bar>) this::check).collectAsList();
```

There is a cast error (!!!):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: test.Bar cannot be cast to test.Foo
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CombineTypedFilters$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$optimizer$CombineTypedFilters$$combineFilterFunction$1.apply(objects.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.CombineTypedFilters$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$optimizer$CombineTypedFilters$$combineFilterFunction$1.apply(objects.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(generated.java:273)
....
```

There are different classes with different properites etc.
Datasets creation are different. (several src files).

**EDIT**:

```
.filter((FilterFunction<Foo>)obj -> check(obj))
```

and

```
.filter((FilterFunction<Bar>)obj -> check(obj))
```

Works correct. There are some problem connected with method reference
 `this::check`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug from Spark, it's [a bug of JDK deserialization (BUG ID: 8154236)](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8154236), deserialization of lambda will cause ClassCastException.
You can see the similar problem description of this issue in [Spark Issues (SPARK-9135)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9135).